# swift - UICollectionView or UIImage - how to prevent image caching

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with 4 `cells` in a grid pattern and no `scrolling`.  Each cell has a single `imageView`.  The `images` are stored in the asset folder and retrieved by name reference (see below).  After some `UI` action, the idea is to

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

and replace the `image` in each `cell`.

Everything works fine, but the memory use keeps `climbing` after each reload.  I had assumed `reloadData()` dumps `unnecessary` `data`, but this experience has me puzzled. What's happening?

If it helps, I read somewhere loading an image with

```
UIImage(name: ...)
```

caches the image.  I've tried to confirm this but have drawn a blank.

My code is pretty straightforward so I'm wondering if this is some memory bug / feature for scrolling purposes (that I don't want).

Once again, I'm looking to stop the memory stockpiling.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your image store in bundle or downloading from server??

Comment: @AmitSingh - the images are kept in the assets folder.

Comment: Yeah thats the reason, Assets folder do work with caching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never had the chance to understand when the image cache is evicted.
Collection view cell are dequeued and reused. That means than right after a cell goes out of screen is put in a recycle bin, if the cell is need again is taken from that recycle bin and placed into you views hierarchy (this is called flyweight pattern I guess), basically you are saving the instantiation cost.
Thus when you deal with images and your images are not stored elsewhere in memory but just inside the image view, every time a cell is shown and an new image is passed to the image view the old image should be freed.
This could not happen if you store a reference to the old image elsewhere, for instance a cache or an array.
To load image from xcasset you can only use `UIImage(name: ...)` that means the image will be cached. Even if Apple says that this cache will be evicted in memory pressure situations and never seen this happening "in time" to avoid the app crashing.
What you can do is do not save in the xcasset folder, but anywhere in your project, in this way they will be loaded into your main bundle, you can load images from here by using the common:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(<#T##name: String?##String?#>, ofType: <#T##String?#>)
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

Pay attention that path is an optional.
As a general rule, always try to save resources by using image of the same view size in pixel, the occupied space of an image means nothing, just how its compressed, when loaded in memory it takes `n_pixel_height * n_pixel_width * n_channels` bytes

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't know how to save my images elsewhere, but this seems like a perfectly good answer.  In the meantime, I'll just live with the caching I guess.

Comment: just an update, I've followed the memory caching as the app runs, and once a memory warning is received, the cache is dumped.  Thanks again for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it correctly, If you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier:, forIndexPath:)` method for cell reusability then it will surely handle the reusability of the cell.

You have no other way to load the images from the bundle.

Some slight changes in memory may reflect but its ok and go ahead

Comment: it doesn't seem right to me that the memory use goes up by 4MB everytime I reload.  I'll run it now and see when it crashes.

Comment: memory use seems to peak at 650MB, probably when all the images have been cycled through.  Still seems excessive considering each image is only about 200kB and there's about 300 of them.

Answer (score -1):

In `prepareForReuse` method of your subclass UICollectionViewCell

```
func prepareForReuse()
{
    super.prepareForReuse();
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just saw this, thought of commenting. What @Proton say might not actually be a bad idea, although he probably meant cellForItemAtIndexPath or cellForRowAtIndexPath. What he is trying to tell you is try to make your image view empty before loading it asynchronously. tldr: like making an "empty image" as your placeholder